# Dump data into dropdownlist using odbcCommand c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, odbc

So far i have tried following:

```
        odbccmd1 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT DISTINCT JCDISTRIBTUION FROM MST WHERE  JOB="+lbljob.text , odbccon);
    odbccon.Open();
    OdbcDataReader ddl = odbccmd1.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList ddll = new DropDownList();
    ddll.DataSource = ddl;
    ddll.DataBind();
```

or this

```
        using (OdbcDataReader CC1 = odbccmd1.ExecuteReader();
    {
        ddlCostC.DataSource = CC1;
        ddlCostC.DataBind();
        CC1.Close();
        ddlCostC.Focus();
    }
```

After many tries, i get following error:

> Data conversion or data mapping error.

All im trying to achieve is, when i select something from dropdownlist and click on "Fetch" button, i would like it to go and fetch codes that are associated with that job and dump them into another dropdownlist.

But every time i have been getting that error. So i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with single quotes for job, assume you have varchar column

```
"SELECT DISTINCT JCDISTRIBTUION FROM MST WHERE  JOB='111111'"
```

without quotes you consider job as number type.

UPDATE:

with Text of text box

```
 odbccmd1 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT DISTINCT JCDISTRIBTUION FROM MST WHERE  JOB='"+lbljob.Text +"'", odbccon);
```

above will work, but you better use parameters like below

```
 odbccmd1 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT DISTINCT JCDISTRIBTUION FROM MST WHERE  JOB=?", odbccon);
 odbccmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("job", lbljob.Text);
```

Comment: It works when i put job in query but when tell it to look at selected value of other dropdown it doesn't work. I tried writing selected value to label/textbox and use that in query but still returns with error `Data conversion or data mapping error.`.

Comment: Last week spent way too much time figuring this out `'"+lbljob.Text +"'"`, Thanks bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing lines similar to these:

```
ddll.DataTextField = "JCDISTRIBTUION ";
ddll.DataValueField = "JCDISTRIBTUION ";
```

Comment: This works when i put static jobnumber under where statement. I am trying to search form other dropdownlist selected value. But i get `Data conversion or data mapping error.` I even tried writing the value to label and then using that but still get same error. Any idea why would this happen?